# Does not set the background correctly and create a blank? Error

Tags: css, background-image

I have the following website:[image]

As it is OK but a blank part because it adds the property CSS3:

```
Background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

why? Because when I adapted the page to mobile it duplicated the background image and I do not want that, which will be the problem this is my CSS of the body does not have any error.

Note I am using the framework CSS:

Bootstrap version 3.3.7

```
Body {
    Background-image: url ("img / imgoriginales / seccionsementales.jpg");
    Background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: try adding `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```css
   background-size:100% 100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

```
body {
  background-image: url ("img/imgoriginales/seccionsementales.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3w8q9ek9/1/**